# Bug with Pulumi Prompt In Terminal

Tags: pulumi

Bug When Displaying Pulumi in any terminal [Bash Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdbIm.png)

When I use Pulumi in a terminal, the prompts are always bugged.
I've tried using Powershell 7, Windows Powershell and Git Bash and it looks the same.

examples

```
$ pulumi up
←[38;5;13m←[1mPreviewing update (dev)←[0m
```

```
Press ←[38;5;14m←[1m^C←[0m at any time to quit.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running the following command to reset the terminal input:

```
tput rmkx
```

This is a known issue with terminal input mode, especially when using .net